# fatal: unexpected command-line argument: reject

Tags: postfix

Good evening.

I have my own private mailserver. Because my university blocks port 25 and my home router seems to have gone mad i tried to open port 587 for smtp but this error popped up.

mail.err:

```
fatal: unexpected command-line argument: reject
```

mail.info:

```
 postfix/master[30098]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

master.cf:

```
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
```

As far as I know the reject is needed from postfix otherwise it wont recieve mail.[Postfix Documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions).

Anyone got an idea what I could/should do?

Comment: Did you make any progress with this HFinch?

Comment: Try deleting the space between the comma and 'reject' on the second to last uncommented line, and restart postfix.

Comment: Hey @PaulS it really was the space in front of the reject! It is working (almost) smooth now but i know how to fix the other problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PaulS suggested the space between the "," and the reject caused postfix to not accept "reject" as a option.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!!! :) Messages before :
Mar 28 15:14:42 smtp02 postfix/submission/smtpd[823]: fatal: unexpected command-line argument: reject
Mar 28 15:14:43 smtp02 postfix/master[32533]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 823 exit status 1
Mar 28 15:14:43 smtp02 postfix/master[32533]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling Changed main.cf line :
from "-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated, reject"
to "-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject" No more error after :)

Comment: Hole smokes... 3-4 hours investigating, and indeed it was a comma between `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject`. The issue was the MTA had been responding with: `Didn't find STARTTLS in server response, trying anyway.... no peer certificate available... SSL handshake has read 0 bytes... New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)...`. Once the comma added: `Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits... SSL handshake has read 4764 bytes and written 415 bytes... New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384... Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived... 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN...`